# How do I quickly display log messages in the UI?

Tags: android

I have a function void `log(String s)` which prints a message into a `TextView` adding it to the existing text. Internally it uses a `Handle`

It does `setText(getText().toString() + s)` but when the text becomes large the whole UI thread freezes.

Is there a way to quickly put log output (like `Log.d`) in the UI thread?

Comment: If the error string is so big that it slows down the UI thread, chances are it would be difficult to read anyhow. Have you tried setting up ACRA or something similar?  It makes managing errors a bit easier than trying to manage them in the UI.

Comment: @RubberMallet Yes, but I'm trying to log some messages, not errors. They are logging fine with Log.d but how to do in UI. I can set up an ArrayAdapter sure, but don't want to.. ACRA is nice but here not related..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just update like this?

```
handler.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        setText(...)
    }
});
```

Or use a StringBuilder for your log messages. The setText(getText()+new log) is really slow.

```
protected StringBuilder logs = new StringBuilder();

void newLogMessage(String msg) { 
    logs.append(msg);
    setText(logs.toString()); 
}
```